# If $\int_{1}^{x} f(t) \ dt = x^2-2x+1$ what is $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus

When solving this problem I was not sure if I could apply the FTC:

> If $\int_{1}^{x} f(t) \ dt = x^2-2x+1$ what is $f(x)$?

May I say that

$$
f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_{1}^{x} f(t) \ dt = [x^2-2x+1]' = 2x-2
$$

Is that correct?

Thank you.

Comment: That is roughly correct, but there is one addition assumption that goes in to it. You need to assume that $f$ is continuous otherwise we can redefine $f$ at a countable number of point and still get the same integral. For example $f(x) = 2x-2$ for $x\not=0$ and $f(0) = 100$ is a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need for $f$ to be continuous over the range of integration, per the assumption of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Your application is correct.

Comment: Thank you again @George. Best Regards.